# how to use filter in spark sql for rates:Struct to get BGN,BRL in range between (2019-01-02 , 2019-01-04)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, date-range

i am working in an example of spark sql. The StructType schema for the dataframe looks like

file.json (schema)

```
root
 |-- rates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2019-01-02: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AUD: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BGN: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BRL: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2019-01-03: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AUD: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BGN: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BRL: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2019-01-04: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AUD: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BGN: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BRL: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2019-02-15: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AUD: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BGN: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BRL: double (nullable = true)
```

---

file.json:-

```
{
  "rates":{
     "2019-02-15": {

      "AUD": 1.4996,
      "GBN": 8.9623,
      "BRL": 137.0 
            },

    "2019-01-02": {
      "AUD": 1.3996,
      "GBN": 8.6623,
      "BRL": 135.0 
            },

    "2019-01-03": {
      "AUD": 1.2996,
      "GBN": 8.7623,
      "BRL": 135.0 
            },

    "2019-01-04": {
      "AUD": 1.2996,
      "GBN": 8.8623,
      "BRL": 136.0 
             }
  }

}
```

---

I just want to display yyyy-mm-dd,BGN and BRL, but the condition is the range is in between(2019-01-02 , 2019-01-04)

output stored as .csv file:- output.csv

```
yyy-mm-dd,BGN,BRL
2019-01-02,8.6623.351,135.0 
2019-01-03,8.7623,135.0
2019-01-04,8.8623,136.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

### Load the test data provided

```scala
    val data =
      """
        |{
        |   "rates": {
        |       "2019-02-15": {
        |
        |           "AUD": 1.4996,
        |           "GBN": 8.9623,
        |           "BRL": 137.0
        |       },
        |
        |       "2019-01-02": {
        |           "AUD": 1.3996,
        |           "GBN": 8.6623,
        |           "BRL": 135.0
        |       },
        |
        |       "2019-01-03": {
        |           "AUD": 1.2996,
        |           "GBN": 8.7623,
        |           "BRL": 135.0
        |       },
        |
        |       "2019-01-04": {
        |           "AUD": 1.2996,
        |           "GBN": 8.8623,
        |           "BRL": 136.0
        |       }
        |   }
        |
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.read.json(Seq(data).toDS)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |rates                                                                                               |
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |[[1.3996, 135.0, 8.6623], [1.2996, 135.0, 8.7623], [1.2996, 136.0, 8.8623], [1.4996, 137.0, 8.9623]]|
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- rates: struct (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- 2019-01-02: struct (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- AUD: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- BRL: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- GBN: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- 2019-01-03: struct (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- AUD: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- BRL: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- GBN: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- 2019-01-04: struct (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- AUD: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- BRL: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- GBN: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- 2019-02-15: struct (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- AUD: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- BRL: double (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- GBN: double (nullable = true)
      */
    // read using file by below command
//    spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("path/to/json/file.json")
```

### Use `stack` function to transpose and then filter using the provided range

```scala
 val df1 = df.selectExpr("rates.*")
    val stringCol = df1.columns.map(c => s"'$c', `$c`").mkString(", ")

    val processedDF = df1.selectExpr(s"stack(${df1.columns.length}, $stringCol) as (`yyyy-MM-dd`, value)")
      .filter(s"`yyyy-MM-dd` between '2019-01-02' and '2019-01-04'")
      .selectExpr("`yyyy-MM-dd`", "value.*")
    processedDF.show(false)
    processedDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +----------+------+-----+------+
      * |yyyy-MM-dd|AUD   |BRL  |GBN   |
      * +----------+------+-----+------+
      * |2019-01-02|1.3996|135.0|8.6623|
      * |2019-01-03|1.2996|135.0|8.7623|
      * |2019-01-04|1.2996|136.0|8.8623|
      * +----------+------+-----+------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- yyyy-MM-dd: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- AUD: double (nullable = true)
      * |-- BRL: double (nullable = true)
      * |-- GBN: double (nullable = true)
      */
    // processedDF can be saved as below
//    processedDF.write
//      .option("header", true)
//      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
//      .csv("/path/to/directory")
```

Comment: if only yyyy-mm-dd & BRL these two column want to show(), and json dataset have more fields under rates:StructType,in such case how to fetch these two column ?

Comment: Use another select Expression on processedDF to fetch only 2 column s

Comment: getting error in  val df = spark.read.json(Seq(data).toDS) , cannot resolve symbol read ?

Comment: Spark is sparkSession instance.

Comment: val df = spa.read.json("/home/rohan/Spark_course_materials/SparkScala3/JsonData/demoData.json").toDF()      ||       getting error   ====    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
(named _corrupt_record by default). For example:
spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count()
and spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).select("_corrupt_record").show().
Instead, you can cache

Comment: how to use json(" fie path ") ?

Comment: and how to store data frame|rdd as .csv file ?

Comment: a dataframe for Spark 2.X can we written in CSV as
`df.write.format("csv").save(filepath)`

Comment: Give me sometime, i ll publish the whole code on github. You just download the repo and try running the testcase.

Comment: @rohanpandole, check update added commented code to read the data from json file and write the output as csv

Comment: @SomeshwarKale, that will be very useful to me

Comment: Please check this testcase-https://github.com/skale1990/ApacheSparkProblemSolving/blob/d0d2c623d76eb4364831cf99ae9f60106a3ab28b/src/test/java/com/som/spark/learning/ProblemSolverJul2020Test.scala#L4097

Comment: @SomeshwarKale thanks for your efforts towards my concern.